# Javascript getting the nth prime number

Tags: javascript

This should return the nth prime (n being the number given by the user). It works fine for the first few numbers (1 returns 2, 2 returns 3, 3 returns 5) but when 5 is given, it returns 9 which isn't prime (it should be 11). This happens with other numbers as well above this (7 returns 15 when it should be 17).

The 'document' stuff is to do with HTML where I'm getting the userValue and to display the prime number.

```
function isPrime(value) {
  for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
      if(value % i === 0) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return value > 1;
}


function generatePrime() {
  var userValue = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;
  var iter = 1;
  var returnValue = 2;
  //checks for an integer
  if (parseInt(userValue) === parseFloat(userValue)) {
    //checks if the user inputted a value above 0
    if (userValue > 0) {
      //loops to find the correct prime
      while (iter < userValue) {
        if (isPrime(returnValue)) {
          returnValue += 1;
          iter += 1;
        }
        if (!isPrime(returnValue)) {
          returnValue += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      returnValue = "That is not a number above 0!";
    }
  }
  else {
    returnValue = "That is not a number!";
  }
  document.getElementById("returnValue").innerHTML = returnValue;
}
```

I need help with making this return the correct number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```js
function nextPrime(value) {
    if (value > 2) {
        var i, q;
        do {
            i = 3;
            value += 2;
            q = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(value));
            while (i <= q && value % i) {
                i += 2;
            }
        } while (i <= q);
        return value;
    }
    return value === 2 ? 3 : 2;
}


function generatePrime() {
 var userValue = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;
 var value = 0, result = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < userValue; i++) {
  value = nextPrime(value);
  result.push(value);
 }
  document.getElementById("returnValue").innerHTML = result[userValue-1];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>

Input value: <input type="text" name="inputValue" id="inputValue"/>
<button onclick="generatePrime()">Prime number</button>
<div id="returnValue">Test: </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please vote up to.. thanks @Laketek for accepting as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
function getNthPrimeNumber(n){
  var count = 0;
  var num = 2;
  while(count++ != n){
    num = getNextPrimeNumber(num);
  }
  return num;
}

function getNextPrimeNumber(n){
  for(var i = ++n; i< n*n; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)) return i
  }
  return 0;
}

function isPrime(n){
  for(var i = 2; i< n; i++)
    if (n%i===0) 
      return false;
  return true;
}

console.log(getNthPrimeNumber(0))
console.log(getNthPrimeNumber(2))
console.log(getNthPrimeNumber(5))
```

Comment: This does work, I'll need to see if I can incorporate it into HTML since I'm working alongside both languages. Thanks :D

Comment: It will. this is just an algo to get nth prime number. Once you get it, you can process accordingly. This is more of a utility function.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the range of iteration for function isPrime() :

```
function isPrime(value) {
  for(var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(value) + 1; i++) {
      if(value % i === 0) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return value > 1;
}
```

Comment: 3 then returns 4 when it should be 5 (also messing up larger nth's)

Comment: you'll earn time if you enter huge value. Because n >> sqrt(n)+1 for big values of n

Comment: I forgot to add the + 1, but even then, 2 returns 5 which isn't right

Comment: No function isPrime(value) just return true or false and is faster if you reduce the range of seek at sqrt(value)+1

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on [Bhaskara Arani's submission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40043617/1762224), but I added caching.

**Note:** I also threw in an addition condition to check for palindrome.

This check can be removed via:

```js
while (i <= root && value % i /* && isPalindrome(value) */)
```

```js
const main = () => {
  for (let i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(`Palindrome Prime ${i + 1} = ${generatePrime(i)}`);
  }
};

const cachedPrimes = [];
const generatePrime = (index) => {
  let value = cachedPrimes[cachedPrimes.length - 1] ?? 0;
  for (let i = cachedPrimes.length; i <= index; i++) {
    value = nextPrime(value);
    cachedPrimes.push(value);
  }
  return cachedPrimes[index];
};

const nextPrime = (value) => {
  if (value > 2) {
    let i, root;
    do {
      i = 3; value += 2; root = ~~Math.sqrt(value);
      while (i <= root && value % i && isPalindrome(value)) {
        i += 2;
      }
    } while (i <= root);
    return value;
  }
  return value === 2 ? 3 : 2;
};

const isPalindrome = (n) => n === reverse(n);

const reverse = n => +`${n}`.split('').reverse().join('');

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```